override where .fmu is unzipped to
Currently using python package FMPY to work with .fmu's.
Working on a security controlled windows environment, I only have whitelisted access to specific directories for my work. This is no issue in python itself, as I can unzip a given .fmu to a directory and then point my code at the unzipped directory to use, rather than let Windows automatically unzip to the AppData area which is restricted and where I cannot execute .dll's etc.
However, the fmpy.gui, and perhaps other means of use of fmpy from the command line, seem to only automatically unzip .fmu to the AppData area, and so will fail.
Does anyone know a way to override this in fmpy?  Or is there some way to direct windows to unzip the .fmu in a specific directory area rather than AppData?
When running <$python -m fmpy.gui> the default behaviour on Windows is to unzip to a temporary directory under the user\AppData\ folder.  Because of restrictions this results in an error since the .dll's that are required cannot be run from here.

Ah, i've discovered the TEMP environment variable controls this behaviour in windows, so I've modified it to point at an area than can be accessed, and now just need to monitor it to make sure this doesn't adversely affect other software.  Cheers!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
